# Animated watermark moving on the edges of the movie - ffmpeg

Tags: animation, ffmpeg, watermark

I wanna overlay a picture on a video, as a watermark. How do I insert an animated watermark that randomly moves from side to side.

For example, 
A watermark, placed on top/ upper-left corner, moves randomly to the top/upper-right corner and freezes there for five seconds before moving  down to the lower- right corner.

I don't want the watermark to have a cross movement and move from the upper-right corner to the lower-left corner.

Here is an example of my code, using which the watermark randomly jumps to a corner each 200 frames without animate:

```
ffmpeg -i "source.mp4" -i "watermark.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=50:-1[a]; [0:v][a]overlay=x='st(0,floor(random(n)*2)+1);if(eq(mod(n-1,200),0), if(eq(ld(0),1),0,  main_w-overlay_w   ) ,x)':y='st(0,floor(random(n)*2)+1);if(eq(mod(n-1,200),0),if(eq(ld(0),1),0,  main_h-overlay_h   ),y)'" -codec:a copy "out.mp4"
```